# Showing that the norm of the image of a $C^1$- function does not have a maximum.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Here's the setup: Let $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ be open and let $f: U \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ function such that $f'(x)$ is invertible for all $x$ in $U$. Show that $x \mapsto ||f(x)||$ does not have a maximum.

Here's my attempt so far: since $f'(x)$ is invertible for all $x$ in $U$, we have that $f(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$. Define $g:f(U) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $g(x)=||x||$. Now suppose $g(f(U))$ is closed in $\Bbb R$. Since $g$ is continuous the inverse image of $g(f(U))$ is closed. But $g^{-1}g(f(U))=f(U)$, which gives a contradiction. Therefore $g(f(U))$ is not closed, so it has the form $[a,b) , (a,b), (a,\infty), (-\infty,a)$ or $(a,b]$ for $a,b \in \Bbb R$, $a<b$. In the first 4 cases we can deduce that $x \mapsto ||f(x)||$ does not have a maximum - but how do I deal with the last case? Also, please point out any flaws in my reasoning so far! Maybe the proof could be much slicker than this.

Comment: Another way: Assume $f(x_0)$ is such a maximum. Since $f(U)$ is open we have that, for $r>0$ small enough $(1+r)f(x_0)\in f(U)$ (why?). This is a contradiction.

Comment: To the 'why?' part: Since $f(U)$ is open there is some $\delta > 0$ such that the ball of radius $\delta$ around $f(x_0)$ is in $f(U)$. Then choose $r>0$ such that $||rf(x_0)||<\delta$. Then $f(x_0) + rf(x_0) \in f(U)$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Very nice approach, I like this, it's almost obvious! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To continue with your approach, you could observe that the map $x\mapsto \|x\|$ is differentiable with nonzero derivative on $\mathbb R^n\setminus 0$. Therefore, it maps open sets to open sets. So, the set $\{\|f(x)\|:f(x)\ne 0\}$ is open in $\mathbb R$, which gives the result.

A slicker way (I think) is to introduce $\phi(x)=\|f(x)\|^2$, which is also $C^1$ and satisfies $ \phi'(x)=2 f'(x)[f(x)] $. (Notation means we plug $f(x)$ into the linear operator $f'(x)$). By assumption, $\phi$ can have critical points only when $f(x)=0$, but those are not points of maximum.

Comment: I was unaware that a function with non-zero derivative maps open sets to open sets. Didn't even occur to me, I'll have a think about proving this.

Comment: To be precise, the derivative should have the rank equal to the dimension of the target space. When the target is one dimensional, this amounts to being nonzero.

Comment: If $f:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ I can see from the inverse function theorem that if the derivative on a open set $U$ has rank=n for all $x \in U$ then $f(U)$ is open - but I'm not quite sure how to deal with the case when the domain and codomain have different dimension. Is there a simple observation or is it a lengthy and/or technical proof?

Comment: It follows from the constant rank theorem, but perhaps you don't have it. Can also be derived from the inverse function theorem, by adding $n-1$ dimensions to the target. But this looks like work. So, I recommend the path outlined in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I think this is an interesting result in itself, though - and perhaps very useful in an exam! I'll read up on the constant rank theorem then.